# Beautiful Soup XML parsing safety

Tags: beautifulsoup

How dangerous is it to parse untrusted xml with Beautiful Soup?

[defusedxml](https://pypi.org/project/defusedxml/) seems to be the go-to module for parsing untrusted xml, however it chokes on malformed xml. I want the leniency of Beautiful Soup, but is it as trustworthy as defusedxml?

List of xml vulnerabilities, for reference:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.html#xml-vulnerabilities

Comment: `bs4` [uses](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) `lxml` as `xml` parser, so I suppose bs4 is as trustworthy as `lxml`.